# git hooks push and local commits

Tags: git, githooks

I have recently been writing git hooks for my project team. I would like to know if developers are making various commits locally, without following the standard commit message pattern. then they push those commits. Will there push fail because there commits weren't following the pattern?

The desired result would be they are able to commit locally as they wish, then are forced to follow a structure way when they push back to the main corporate branch.

Thoughts? Is this the best practice?

Comment: "Will their push fail because their commits don't follow the pattern?" : if you write a hook that will reject their push if their commits don't follow the pattern, then yes. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: my question was if i write a commit hook that check for a pattern and they dont follow the pattern locally. will there push fail? or is there a push-hook? :) sorry if i wasn't clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is: [git hooks](http://progit.org/book/ch7-3.html) are not published (pushed/pulled)

So if your project members push to a bare repo where a server-side hook (`pre-receive` or `update`) check for the commit message pattern (which I am not sure it can be done), that push will fail.
But the commit lives on the developer local repo and he/she still has to fix it (`git commit --amend` if no other commits have already been done).

It would be better to:

- make a **template** Git repo with the right hooks
- make sure the developers initialize their repo with the --template option referencing the right common template.
  See **[template directory section](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-init.html#_template_directory)** of `git init`.

That way, they will fail quicker than on the server side (where n incorrect commits can be pushed, and will fail)

In other work, here a client-side hook would be more appropriate.